# Include different .php files in JS popup

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, popup

I have multiple buttons which currently redirect to different pages for users to perform a single action and they would then need to click another button whilst on the confirmation page to go back where they were before. This is old school and inconvenient...

What I would like to do is create 1 single pop-up box which would get triggered (appear) when any of those buttons are clicked. Inside the box, I want the relevant .php file to appear so users can confirm their action and the page would then reload and display a confirmation message.

Example:
"Delete" button needs to trigger the confirmation-popup.php to appear with the delete.php file included in it so users can confirm the deletion.

"Cancel" button needs to trigger the confirmation-popup.php to appear with the cancel.php file included in it so users can confirm the cancellation.

Here's what I've done:
- Created the pop up and included it on their Account page (that's where all the buttons are).
- Added a JS which passes through the button ID to trigger the popup

When either of the buttons is clicked, the popup would appear fine.
I'm stuck at the stage where different "action".php files need to passed and included in the body of the popup. I know I could create multiple popups each for its relevant action, but we all know this isn't best practice and it's doubling up.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Added code after the below comment

HTML:

`<a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>/?a_action=delete_auction&pid=<?php the_ID(); ?>"><button class="button-small button-red" id="confirm-delete">Delete</button></a>`

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#confirm-delete").click(function() {

        if (!$(".confirm-popup").is(":visible")) {
            $(".confirm-popup").fadeIn("slow");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

PHP confirm_popup.php:

```
<div class="confirm-popup">
<?php include 'delete_auction.php'; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, verifiable, complete example in your question. In other words, your codes. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open different iframes in the popup based on the button pressed. That will allow you to use one popup and you will just edit the iframe src attribute to the correct php page. For example you can add an HTML attribute to each button that holds the URL of the page that should be opened by the button. Then you will have some JS code that on the button press will read the attribute that holds the URL and puts it in the iframe src attribute inside the popup.

Something like this using jQuery:

```
<button class="myclass" cotent-url="delete.php">Delete</button>
<button class="myclass" cotent-url="save.php">Save</button>
<div class="popup"><iframe src=""></iframe></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.myclass').click(function(){
    $('.popup iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('content-url'));
})
</script>
```

Or AJAX way:

```
<button class="myclass" cotent-url="delete.php">Delete</button>
<button class="myclass" cotent-url="save.php">Save</button>
<div class="popup"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.myclass').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('content-url'),
        data: {},
        success: function(response) {
            $('.popup').html(response);
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just to confirm... Do you mean something along the lines of `<button class="anyclass">Delete<iframe src="delete.php"</iframe></button>`
I've never worked with iframe, so wondering if this is the right approach. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks heaps! This is what I needed, a way to pass in the relevant php depending on the action required.

Comment: Just to add in case anybody needs help. There's a minor typo in the jQuery script..


`<button class="myclass" content-url="delete.php">Delete</button>


<button class="myclass" content-url="save.php">Save</button>


<div class="popup"><iframe src=""></iframe></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('.myclass').click(function(){

    $('.popup iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('content-url'));

})
</script>`